How to handle In-App Update Flexible in configuration change?
Is there a way to keep InstallStateUpdatedListener callbacks after configuration change when using Flexible flow with In-App Update? I tried the following but the callback for InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED always lost after screen rotation.
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding, MainSharedViewModel>(),
    InstallStateUpdatedListener {

    private var isAppUpdateOngoing = false

    private lateinit var inAppUpdateDialog: AlertDialog

    private lateinit var inAppUpdateResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>

    private val appUpdateManager by inject<AppUpdateManager>()

    private val userPreferences by inject<UserPreferences>()

    override val viewModel by viewModel<MainSharedViewModel>()

    override fun bindingInflater(): (LayoutInflater) -> ActivityMainBinding =
        ActivityMainBinding::inflate

    override fun initViews(binding: ActivityMainBinding) {

        // In case where Activity was recreated, reinitialize
        inAppUpdateResultLauncher = activityForResultIntentSender { result, _ ->

            when (result.resultCode) {
                // In flexible flow, the user accepted the request to update.
                // In immediate flow, the user accepted and the update succeeded (which, in practice, your app never should never receive because it already updated).
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> isAppUpdateOngoing = true

                // In flexible flow, the user denied the request to update.
                // In immediate flow, the user denied or canceled the update.
                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> unregisterInAppUpdateListener()

                // In flexible flow, something failed during the request for user confirmation. For example, the user terminates the app before responding to the request.
                // In immediate flow, the flow failed either during the user confirmation, the download, or the installation.
                ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED -> {
                    recordException("In-App Update Unknown Failure")
                    showToast(getString(R.string.unknown_error))
                }
            }

        }

            inAppUpdateDialog = materialDialog(
                getString(R.string.update_success),
                null,
                getString(R.string.install_update),
                { dialog, _ ->
                    appUpdateManager.completeUpdate() // Install updates
                    dialog.dismiss()
                },
                null,
                null,
                false
            ).create()

        }

    }

    override fun subscribeUI(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // Try to recover the UI state during configuration change or system-initiated process death
        isAppUpdateOngoing = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(AppConfig.IS_APP_UPDATE_ONGOING, false) == true

    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        // Store the UI state that can survive even a System-initiated system-initiated process death
        outState.putBoolean(AppConfig.IS_AD_FETCHED, isAdFetched)
        outState.putBoolean(AppConfig.IS_APP_UPDATE_ONGOING, isAppUpdateOngoing)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (isAppUpdateOngoing.not()) {
            appUpdateManager.checkUpdates(inAppUpdateResultLauncher, this)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        inAppUpdateDialog.dismiss()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        backPressedCallback.remove()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onStateUpdate(state: InstallState) {

        when (state.installStatus()) {

            InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED -> {

                if (isDestroyed.not() && isFinishing.not()) {
                    inAppUpdateDialog.show()
                }

            }

            InstallStatus.INSTALLED -> {
                unregisterInAppUpdateListener()
            }

            InstallStatus.CANCELED, InstallStatus.FAILED, InstallStatus.UNKNOWN -> {
                recordException("In-App Update Failed Status Code: ${state.installErrorCode()}")
                unregisterInAppUpdateListener()
            }

            InstallStatus.DOWNLOADING,
            InstallStatus.INSTALLING,
            InstallStatus.PENDING -> {
                /* no-op */
            }

            else -> {
                recordException("In-App Update Unknown Status Code: ${state.installErrorCode()}")
                unregisterInAppUpdateListener()
            }

        }

    }

    private fun unregisterInAppUpdateListener() {
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

}

AppUpdateManager extension
fun AppUpdateManager.checkUpdates(
    updateFlowResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>,
    listener: InstallStateUpdatedListener
) {

    val intentSenderForResultStarter =
        IntentSenderForResultStarter { intent, _, fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, _, _ ->
            val request = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent)
                .setFillInIntent(fillInIntent)
                .setFlags(flagsValues, flagsMask)
                .build()

            updateFlowResultLauncher.launch(request)
        }

    appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->

        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {

            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS || (appUpdateInfo.updatePriority >= 4 && appUpdateInfo.isImmediateUpdateAllowed)) {
                startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    intentSenderForResultStarter,
                    AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                        .setAllowAssetPackDeletion(true)
                        .build(),
                    DEFAULT_VALUE_INTEGER
                )
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.isFlexibleUpdateAllowed) {

                // Callback to let user manually install the updates
                registerListener(listener)

                startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    intentSenderForResultStarter,
                    AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
                        .setAllowAssetPackDeletion(true)
                        .build(),
                    DEFAULT_VALUE_INTEGER
                )

            }

        }

    }

}

I am using Koin for creating singleton instance of AppUpdateManager
single {
        AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(androidApplication())
    }

